# How can I automatically sign applications for billing?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, code-signing, in-app-billing

I'm having a few issues with Android/Eclipse with using Android Market Billing. I have to sign my application properly for it to work (according to the dev guide), but I don't want to have to go through the whole process all the time.

Is there a step I can add to Eclipse so it'll automatically sign the APK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Ant](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html) to export a signed APK with a single command. There is no single-click 'Export signed APK' action in Eclipse.

Comment: Ah right. I don't think I'm going to use Market Billing then, it's too much faff

Comment: That's certainly not a reason to give up IAB. You can do most of your testing with a debug build and the test products. You only need to use a release APK for final testing.

Comment: Oh, I just kept getting "DEVELOPER_ERROR" :/

Comment: @Nikolay Elenkov : You can not test In App Purchase without signed build in Android.

Comment: All builds are signed, but with the debug version you can only test products ('android.test.purchased', etc.).

Comment: @Nikolay Elenkov: Can we test multiple items with same ProductId `android.test.purchased` with debug keystore?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Export Wizard from Package Explorer.
With 3 simple steps you are ready to publish on an application marketplace such as Google Play.

Check the link below for more info
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#ExportWizard

Comment: But I don't want to do that EVERY time I want to push out a build